# How can I change the colour of the blue line on tabs when the Holo theme is used?

Tags: android, themes, tabcontrol, android-theme

I'm creating an Android app that uses the Holo Dark theme. When I add a TabControl there is a blue line under each tab that increases in height when that tab is selected.

Is it possible to change the colour of this line per tab, so that the line on each tab is a different colour?